# Accessing an embedded schema in a components meta data with the Java API

Tags: 2011, java, metadata

I've encountered an issue with the Java API that has me scratching my head. I have created a component with a metadata of which one field is a multi value embedded schema. I'm trying to access it to return it separately. This:

```
Map <String, NameValuePair> map = cMeta.getNameValues();
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
```

Shows that it is there when I loop through as I get all of the fields, including the contentCollection noted below.

However when I access the collection directly?

```
Object componentKeywordObj = cMeta.getValue("contentCollection");
```

Which should contain a group of the values listed from the above iterator, it returns null?

The java documentation is so scant I can't find anything on what I might be doing wrong. Anyone have any ideas? Do you have to access a multi valued embedded schema differently?

Any help much appreciated.